# jQuery multiple div show hide function using anchor point

Tags: jquery, html, hide, anchor, show

http://jsfiddle.net/BXNE9/1/ I want to open div through anchor point using related link. when I click the link the related div is showing but when I click on other link the previous div is also showing.

I want to open div on related link through anchor point but when I click the other link the previous div need to close. Same in all links and related divs. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hide all divs in the click callback like this

```
var tabs = $('ul.menu li a');

    tabs.bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var ids = tabs.each(function(){
           $($(this).attr('href')).hide();   
        });
        $($anchor.attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/BXNE9/2/

When user click on a link I am first hiding all divs using a [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do this.. div a css class to parent div and

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:450px; margin-top:50px;">

<div style="width:350px; height:250px; margin:0 auto;" class="test">
<div id="firstDiv" style="background:#03F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">First Div</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="background:#06F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Second Div</div>
<div id="thirdDiv" style="background:#09F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Third Div</div>
<div id="fourthDiv" style="background:#0CF; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Fourth Div</div>
</div>
```

​

js code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tabs = $('ul.menu li a');

    tabs.bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $(".test div").fadeOut('slow');
        $($anchor.attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');

        event.preventDefault();
    });


});​
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXNE9/3/) for that..

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to put a class or id onto the div surrounding the elements that fade in:

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:450px; margin-top:50px;">

<div class="fadein" style="width:350px; height:250px; margin:0 auto;">

    <div id="firstDiv" style="background:#03F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">First Div</div>
    <div id="secondDiv" style="background:#06F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Second Div</div>
    <div id="thirdDiv" style="background:#09F; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Third Div</div>
    <div id="fourthDiv" style="background:#0CF; width:350px; height:250px; float:left; display:none;">Fourth Div</div>

</div>
```

and then use .children to hide them before fading in the new one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tabs = $('ul.menu li a');

    tabs.bind('click',function(event){
        $('.fadein').children().hide();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $($anchor.attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
        event.preventDefault();
    });


});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXNE9/4/